# Help defining the sapience tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I just created a new tag of [sapience](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sapience). I noted a number of questions that asked about the evolution of sapient level creatures and felt that it would be nice to be able to tag these sort of questions with both evolution *and* sapience.

I want the tag to be more general then just evolution of sapience, to instead include both questions about sapience itself and to include questions about creatures that are sapient including things such as how does one set policies for deciding if an alien species is sapient, evolution of sapience, what would happen if a creature were uplifted to sapience artificially, what would happen if you had a species that included sapient and non-sapient members etc.

I think the tag is useful, but I don't really like the tag description I gave.  I was hoping someone could help me word-smith it slightly to make it better describe the general idea.

Also, due to the confusion between sentient and sapient I would want the tag to describe a *very* brief description of what sapient is, something like "human level intellect", to avoid confusion of those who don't know the word or often confuse it with sentience.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is *Sentience* what you are going for?

Comment: sapient:  having or showing great wisdom or sound judgement

Comment: sentient:  having the power of perception by the senses; conscious.

Comment: @james, no I want sapient.  A dog is sentient, only a human (okay and maybe some great apes, dolphins, and a hand full of other species depending on who you ask and exactly what level one holds sapience to) are sapient.  Sentience is a boring topic, sapience, human-level intellect, is an interesting one.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> For questions about sapience or sapient creatures.  Includes human or above intelligence, or beings which possess (or will evolve) that level of intelligence.